# Can 々 stand for a duplicated kanji with a different reading?

Tags: kanji, orthography, multiple-readings, symbols, irregularities-exceptions

The title may not be so clear, here is what I mean:

々 is used to avoid repeating a *kanji*. In some cases, the two may not be pronounced the same because the first consonant of the second *kanji* is voiced (e.g. [時]{とき}[々]{どき}), but they still have the same reading.

Are there cases where the two have different readings (*kun'yomi* and *on'yomi*, or two different *kun* or two different *on*)?

Answer (score 12):

I wouldn't necessarily say 々 is used to avoid having to write the same *kanji* again, but rather to make it clear that the word is obtained by duplication of a character — moreover the reading should be doubled (with *rendaku* where applicable).

For example, 日本国語大辞典 (via [kotobank.jp](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%80%85-597338)) has

> **のま【々】**
>
> (「々」が、かたかなの「ノ」と「マ」を組み合わせたように見えるところからの通称。「ノマ」とかたかなで表記する) 同じ漢字が続いて繰り返されるとき、第二字に代えて用いる記号で、**読みは第一字に従う**。漢字の「繰り返し記号」で、重字、畳字ともいい、かたかなの「ヽ」、ひらがなの「ゝ」とともに「おどり字」の一種。その形は「仝」の変形ともいわれるが、中国でも用いられていた二点
>   「[image]」
>   が日本で変化して出来たものか。同の字点。
>
> <sup>日本国語大辞典 via [kotobank.jp](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%80%85-597338), emphasis added</sup>

Whether you take it as a hard rule or not, I don't think anyone would think it a good idea to use 々 when then reading of the *kanji* is different.

For example, one usually writes

- 日々 *hibi*
- 日にち *hinichi*

In principle both can also be written 日日 (which they usually aren't for disambiguation), but I don't think that 日々 would ever be used to mean 日にち.

---

Just for fun, there is of course 明々後日 *shiasatte*, but this is probably not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. For example, here are two places in Chiba:

- 酒々井 (しすい)
- 行々林 (おどろばやし)

You could also make arguments for 神々廻 (ししば), too.